# Simple Add / Remove Component Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, reactjs

I'm quite confused about this pattern in React. I have seen it in other places it but it does not seem correct.

Given the below code:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = window.React = require('react'),
    Item = require("./ui/Item");

var ItemApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      items: [ "Example Item" ] // we want one thing to render initially
    };                          // so prepopulate with one thing
  },
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
      index: 1
    }
  },
  onAddItem: function (e) {
    var debts = this.state.debts.push( "New Item " + this.props.index);
    this.setState({ items: this.state.items });
    this.props.index++;
  },
  onRemoveItem: function (i) {
    // splice here
    this.state.items.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ items: this.state.items });
    this.props.index--;
  },
  render: function () {
    var items = this.state.items;
    var closeFn = this.onRemoveItem;
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12">
        <div className="cold-md-3"></div>
        <div className="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.onAddItem}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Debt</button>
        </div>
        {items.map(function (item, i) {
          return <Item name={item} closeFn={closeFn.bind(null, i)} key={i} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The example above works like intended (it's a list and you can add and remove things at will) however whenever I add something renders the whole thing over again.

So after only adding one component the whole thing has rendered 3 times. After clicking twice it will have rendered 5 times. You can see why this might be a problem.

This seems really inefficient is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I advise against using `this.state.items.splice(i, 1);` - direct mutation of state is a bad practice. `this.setState()` starts a state transition right after you mutated state-see more [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

Comment: Either way the component will render multiple times.

Comment: Every time you call setState() on a component, the component will re-render. The state has changed because there are different items-why wouldn't you want to re-render to show the updated state of the component?

Comment: I just figured that it would append a new <Item /> rather than delete whats there and render two new <Item />s.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, I suggest reading [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/docs/docs/ref-08-reconciliation.md) about how React's diffing algorithim works. I've found React to be quite performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manually manage the dom, react probably isn't for you.  You can always do it better than the abstraction if you really want to.

In react, it's usually best to aim for code that can clearly express its intent to react, and let it do its thing.

You code is close, the only problem is your `key` attributes don't uniquely reflect the items in the array.  Index based keys are 100% fine for when you have a stack.  I gave a [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258517/react-js-input-element-renders-differently-compared-to-other-elements/28262763#28262763) to a similar question.

To actually solve this here, because any item can be removed at any time, you need to encode a unique identifier in the item itself.  Instead of storing an array of strings `["a", "b", "c"]` you should store an array of objects `[{id: '1', text: "a"}, {id: '2', text: "b"}, {id: '3', text: "c"}]`.  You can then use the id as your key and it'll be more efficient.

---

This is unrelated to the question, but `this.props.index--` is modifying props, which is bad and unreliable.  If you need to keep a counter for some reason, set it directly on `this` in componentWillMount.  If you need to communicate something up the tree, you accept a callback as a prop, and call that.

Also `<Item name={item} closeFn={closeFn.bind(null, i)} key={i} />` doesn't describe any way to get data back out of the Item, other than when deletion is requested.

Comment: Yes, the way in which the keys are set in the original post are causing objects to be unnecessarily re rendered.  Since the keys are index based, when an object is removed there is potential for a large portion of the elements (depending on which index is removed) having new keys, and having to rerender because react thinks those items have changed.