# Deleting Stateful element from ReactJS array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issues with removing stateful elements in an React array. In the following example, if you click 'toggle' on the second element ('B'), you will see:

> Entry id: 0 name: A Is Active Toggle Remove
>
> Entry id: 1 name: B Is Not Active Toggle Remove
>
> Entry id: 2 name: C Is Active Toggle Remove

If you now click 'Remove' on the first element ('A'):

> Entry id: 0 name: B Is Active Toggle Remove
>
> Entry id: 1 name: C Is Not Active Toggle Remove

B has changed, but all I wanted to do was delete A and not impact any other elements. I've got a `key` as per the docs, and have tried using a key with a string prefix but it didn't help.

Is there any way to do this without pushing state up to `TestContainer`? (In my real situation I have a lot of disparate elements with different types of states).

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script type="text/jsx">

  var TestLine = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
          return {active: true};
      },
      handleLineRemove: function(e) {
        this.props.processLineRemove(this.props.id);
      },
      toggleActive: function(e) {
        this.setState({active: !this.state.active};
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
          <p>
            Entry id: {this.props.id} name: {this.props.name}
            {this.state.active ? " Is Active " : " Is Not Active " }
            <a onClick={this.toggleActive}>Toggle</a>
            &nbsp;<a onClick={this.handleLineRemove}>Remove</a>
          </p>
        );
      }
    });

     var TestContainer = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {data: {lines: ['A','B','C']}};
        },
        processLineRemove: function(index) {
              var new_lines = this.state.data.lines.slice(0);
              new_lines.splice(index,1);
              var newState = React.addons.update(this.state.data, {
                lines: {$set: new_lines}
              });
          this.setState({data: newState});
        },
        render: function() {
            var body =[];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.state.data.lines.length; i++) {
                body.push(<TestLine 
                          key={i}
                          id={i}
                          name={this.state.data.lines[i]}
                          processLineRemove={this.processLineRemove} />)
            }
            return (
                <div>{body}</div>
            );
        }
    });

React.render(<TestContainer />, document.getElementById('test'));
</script>
```

Comment: There always will need to be some centralized location that will need to be notified of the deletion. You could use an action/dispatcher to notify of the change and have it propagate back, but conceptually it's not much different  from your existing implementation as shown. You'll need to notify whatever component or store owns the data.

Comment: Elements are getting deleted successfully via TestContainer which owns the array. However the remaining array elements are not re-rendered correctly; merely the name labels are being moved and the private state in TestLine is not 'moved over' to the new position in the array.

Comment: You're asking two questions then -- how to manage state without involving the `TestContainer` and how to re-render correctly. It looks like the answer should help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a list with arbitrary removals/insertions, you can't use index as a key.  In this case, you could use the actual value because it isn't changed.

```js
var body = this.state.data.map(function(x, i){
    return <TestLine 
        key={x}
        name={x}
        processLineRemove={this.processLineRemove.bind(null, i)} />
}.bind(this));
```

In more complicated case, you need an array of objects, and you assign a property with a unique value to each.  Assuming state is `[makeItem('A'), makeItem('B'), ...]`:

```js
function unique(){ return ++unique.i };
unique.i = 0;

function makeItem(text){ return {text: text, id: unique()}; };

var body = this.state.data.map(function(x, i){
    return <TestLine 
        key={x.id}
        name={x.text}
        processLineRemove={this.processLineRemove.bind(null, i)} />
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of items and you know that items will be edited randomly, I would not create the keys like that. I would rather create keys that unique and `will not overlap` with other keys upon list change. A simple random key generator like [this](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/react/js/utils.js#L7) should suffice.

Why ? Lets go over each step.

First renders looks like this

> Entry id: 0 name: A Is Active Toggle Remove
>
> Entry id: 1 name: B Is Not Active Toggle Remove
>
> Entry id: 2 name: C Is Active Toggle Remove

And second looks like this

> Entry id: 0 name: B Is Not Active Toggle Remove
>
> Entry id: 1 name: C Is Active Toggle Remove

Now it is React's time to take these two, and figure out what changed. It will compare the components and the keys.

It looks at the first element and understands that the "active" flag is set to true based on the key. So it will apply the same to the key 0 that is finds in the second render. So on and so forth for the remaining elements.

Thus if your keys do not overlap upon change you can avoid this issue.
This is the only way AFAIK. Hope this helps.

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cavuf/1/edit?html,output) explaining the above.

[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258517/react-js-input-element-renders-differently-compared-to-other-elements/28262763#28262763)

Comment: UUID solves the problem of many servers creating up to billions of uuids per second with nearly 0% chance of conflict.  It's a bit overkill here.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand would https://lodash.com/docs#uniqueId make more sense, for example (with a prefix ?)